# Максимальное количество значений в массиве 10 Swift / Firebase

Tags: массивы, swift, firebase

Эта система подписок и подписчиков как в instagram, когда один из моих пользователей подписался на 11 пользователей, приложение начало падать для него с ошибкой Thread 1: "Invalid Query. Фильтры 'in' поддерживают максимум 10 элементов в массиве значений.". Чтобы избежать повторяющихся вопросов, я просмотрел все похожие вопросы, и ни один из методов мне не помог

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import ProgressHUD

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    @Published var user: User
    @Published var followedUsers = [User]()
    @Published var followersUsers = [User]()
    @Published var followedUsersAny = [User]()
    @Published var followersUsersAny = [User]()

    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        fetchFollowedUsers()
        fetchFollowersUsers()
        fetchFollowedUsersAny()
        fetchFollowersUsersAny()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel {
 func fetchFollowedUsers() {
        self.isLoading = true
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("following").getDocuments { followersSnapshot, _ in
            guard let followerDocuments = followersSnapshot?.documents else { return }
            let followedUsers = followerDocuments.map({ $0.documentID })
            
            if !followedUsers.isEmpty {
                COLLECTION_USERS.whereField("uid", in: followedUsers).getDocuments { tweetsSnapshot, _ in
                    guard let tweetDocuments = tweetsSnapshot?.documents else { return }
                    self.followedUsers = tweetDocuments.map({ User(dictionary: $0.data()) })
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            } else {
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Страница, которая отображает все подписки

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserFollowedView: View {
    let emptyFollowing : LocalizedStringKey = "emptyFollowing"
    let emptyFollowingAny: LocalizedStringKey = "emptyFollowingAny"
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
    let user : User
    
    init(user: User){
        self.user = user
        self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(user: user)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            if AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid == user.id {
                if viewModel.followedUsers.isEmpty {
                    Text(emptyFollowing)
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.followedUsers) { user in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    UserProfileView(user: user)
                                } label: {
                                    UserCell(user: user)
                                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                        .background(
                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                                .fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                                .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.systemPurple).opacity(0.3), radius: 7, x: 0, y: 4)
                                        )
                                    //                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 1)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if viewModel.followedUsersAny.isEmpty {
                    Text(emptyFollowingAny)
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.followedUsersAny) { user in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    UserProfileView(user: user)
                                } label: {
                                    UserCell(user: user)
                                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                        .background(
                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                                .fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                                .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.systemPurple).opacity(0.3), radius: 7, x: 0, y: 4)
                                        )
                                    //                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 1)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас вот здесь COLLECTION_USERS.whereField("uid", in: followedUsers) больше 10 followedUsers. Нужно или переписать это выражение или найти другой вариант массовой выборки.